# Sequential querying mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL database which has a similar fields structure to below:

[image]

I need to query the **Question** field in a sequential way. Meaning, I need to check if **Q1** is answered and then go to **Q2** and so on.

I'm aware if I have a primary key defined or a numerical value in a parallel column I can use a PHP `while` loop to sequentially look at it.

However in the absence of such a numerical column field, is it possible to capture numerical value attached to the letter "**Q**" in the **Question** field to query? or is there another method?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to `.append` each and every row in the table via jQuery to a `<div />` tag through a `click` event, hence the necessity to query the data in a sequential manner.

If in the data table, questions are stored in a random way (i.e : Q1, Q3, Q2) I need to append data like Q1, Q2 and Q3.

Comment: Have you tried using `foreach` instead of a while loop?

Comment: is this some form of survey database that happens over a period of time and that a user gets to finish off what they didn't answer like a month later (for example), or is this for a "per session" thing? the question is unclear for me in that respect.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner pardon for the lack in clarity, trust the edit suffice.